# Object in array isn't really working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a custom object that also has an html object within it that I made that adds itself (`this`) to an array but when I try to call it from the array, it returns a string of [object Object] instead and does some really wonky stuff too...

I have done many things like: give it a function that returns itself and then call that, change syntax etc.

```
var array = [];
var obj = function () {
     var t = document.createElement('div');
     this.element = t;
     array+=this;
}
for (i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
     console.log(array[i]);
}
```

I expected to get the actual object but instead got each individual character of the string [object Object]

Reason being for me doing `this.element` is because I challenged myself to make a arcade game (Space invaders) using just Js,CSS, and HTML and no canvasses

The simple reason for using `this` is because I want practice with it's logic and syntax

Pls help

Thanks aggressive neckbeards(Chill out I'm only joking)

Comment: To append the object to the array, call `array.push(this);`

Comment: WTH is `array+=this`?

Comment: `+=` is not a valid operator for arrays to my knowledge. The [`.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method will add an element to the end of an array

Comment: It's not really clear what you are hoping `this` is when you write `this.element = t`. Maybe it you add some explanation of why you are using `this` here, someone will be a able to provide  a good explanation.

Comment: I don't know how exactly how to reply to comments but thanks everyone and += has always worked for me, I'm completely self taught so I didn't know about array.push()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an element to an array you can either use the push method

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];
array.push(5);
console.log(array);
```

or you can create a new array with the spread operator

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4];
console.log([...array, 5]);
```

+= will comma concatenation the array and add the new element to the end of the string

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4];
console.log(array += 5);
```

Comment: Ok thank you so much! The ```+=``` operator works like a charm for me normally but now I see the error of my ways, again, thanks!